# Segmentation fault while incrementing pointer to a struct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault in this program. I think its in line where I'm incrementing pointer `ptr` as `ptr++`. `ptr` is a structure type pointer. I have also used `malloc` function to allocate memory. Please suggest some solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA 3000

int main() {

  struct two {
    char SName[15];
    float m15, Mb, v, v_Si, R_Si, t;
  };

  struct two * ptr;

  ptr = (struct two * ) malloc(DATA * (sizeof(struct two)));

  float min_m15, min_Mb, min_v, min_v_Si, min_R_Si, min_t;
  float max_m15 = 1.93;
  min_m15 = 0.93;
  min_Mb = -19.69;
  min_v = 10.0;
  min_v_Si = 8.5;
  min_R_Si = 0.1;
  min_t = -5.0;

  for (min_m15 = .93; min_m15 <= 1.93; min_m15 = min_m15 + .1) {

    ptr -> m15 = min_m15;
    ptr -> Mb = min_Mb;
    ptr -> v = min_v;
    ptr -> v_Si = min_v_Si;
    ptr -> R_Si = min_R_Si;
    ptr -> t = min_t;
    ptr++;

  }

  free(ptr);
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Incrementing a pointer does not give a segmentation fault.

Your problem is with `free(ptr)`. In the [Linux man page for `free`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) it says:

> The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, **which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`**.

As your program runs, `ptr` gets incremented, becomes different from the value returned by previous call to `malloc`, resulting in segmentation fault when you call `free(ptr)`.